# How can I convert NSNumber to float?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use `atoaf([myNSNumberobject UTF8String])` and it works but gives me a warning:

> NSNumber may not respond to UTF8String

How can I convert NSNumber to float?

Comment: Always check the docs. This one would have been obvious!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does your `NSNumber` object contain a float?

Just use `[number floatValue]`, where `number` is an `NSNumber` object.

Comment: I have asked some questions in the past which I like to leave feedback but I can not find them.  Is there anyway I can look at all my questions?

Comment: Your username shows up in a few places as a link to your profile.